# tensors and transformation laws

Tags: tensors

initially we defined tensors as linear transformations but now we're making the assumption that they can also be defined through the use of transformation laws, how does both definitions correlate?

[image]

[image]

source: introduction to continuum mechanics by Lai

Comment: Defining tensors via change-of-coordinate rules is something obsolete nowadays and, in my openion, wrong. I think it is better for you to consider tensors simply as multilinear maps.

Comment: i already grasped that concept while studying linear algebra but right now i'd like to wrap my mind around this new definition.

Comment: Well that definition follows from the direct fact that they are linear combinations of elements of the form $e_i\otimes e_j\otimes e_k\dots$. Try to express the tensor in a new basis and look what happens with the coordinates.

Comment: I should also mention that the ''tensorial behaviour'' extends further. I haven't ever been interested because it's something I think isn't rigorous. However, if you really wan to know more about it you should start reading Wiki and find there further references. In particular, I am thinking about the case of the 2-forms of curvature $\Omega^i_j$. You can think simply that there are $n^2$ $2$-forms and that the indices label them. However, they transform in a "covariant way" and people (especially physicists) like saying they are ''tensor indices'. I think something old-fashioned but...